# Creating PHP code within HTML

Tags: php, apache, spam-prevention

I'm trying to create a block of PHP code within HTML such that when the user loads the page, it displays their IP address and time/date as the user in an email address.

I'm using apache on fedora21, and have enabled PHP (tested with phpinfo() function in the same HTML file).

Here is the code I'm trying to execute:

```
<? echo '<a href="mailto:'.$REMOTE_ADDR.'_'.date('y-m-j').'-@example.com"  title="There is no spoon">For stupid spambots'; ?>
```

It just prints `For stupid spambots'; ?>` without printing the generated email address.

Comment: What if you close link with `</a>`?

Comment: You forgot the closure tag `</a>` after `spambots'` besides that the rest of your code will only show if you view the source code and the `There is no spoon` should show if you hover over it

Comment: To return IP address, use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` instead of `$REMOTE_ADDR`. Please look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) for more.

Comment: Closing the tag didn't help. I changed the <? to <?php and that enabled it to be parsed correctly.

I also added $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] to properly print the IP address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<? echo '<a href="mailto:'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'_'.date('y-m-j').'-@example.com"  title="There is no spoon">For stupid spambots</a>'; ?>
```

Need to close `<a href` at first, and if you want to return IP its `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` not `$REMOTE_ADDR` except you define that variable before.

Comment: Turns out I didn't need to close the <a href and was able to just change the $REMOTE_ADDR with the $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']. I added <?php to get it to parse the php.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the fact that you can see closing `?>`, I deduce that your PHP code doesn't run at all and is interpreted like regular HTML.

There might be several reasons why (badly configured Apache being one of them), but my prime suspect is that you have disabled short PHP tags. Try using `<?php` instead of `<?`.

Comment: Adding the <?php enabled the code to be processed correctly. It looks like short_open_tag is indeed set to Off. Is there any downside to enabling it?

Comment: The main issue I'm aware of is that enabling it can cause `<?` in XML's `<?xml version="1.0"?>` being treated as PHP opening tag (and cause syntax error with undefined identifier "xml"). Most configurations have it disabled, and nowadays it's perceived as a legacy option used for backwards compatibility with older projects, I guess.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. It's likely the code I started with was a few years old, so maybe it was more frequently used then.

Answer (score 0):

You used the syntax of an html anchor wrong. Consider this:

```
<?php 
$address = sprintf('%s_%s-@example.com', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], date('y-m-j'));
echo sprintf('<a href="mailto:%1$s" title="%2$s">%3$s: %1$s</a>', 
             $address,
             'There is no spoon',
             'For stupid spambots'); 
?>
```

You have to print the address into the visible text content of the anchor definition if you want it to be visible. You only but the "For stupid spambots" string in there which is what got displayed.

( Note that I just used the `sprintf()` calls to keep the lines short and readable. Obviously this also works with traditional string concatenation. )

Comment: This didn't work for me. It printed:

    %3$s: %1$s', $address, 'There is no spoon', 'For stupid spambots'); ?>

Comment: Ok, this sure works, but indeed you actually need a working php setup first. From your description I understood you had that. Ho come you lost it inbetween?